# Sort Documents And Media & Web Content in Liferay 6.2 by date

Tags: sorting, liferay, liferay-6

I don't found how to sort my documents & web contents by date in the Liferay back office. I suppose that i have to modify a special JSP in the hook...

i expect a default sorting. When the user goes to the documents and media, i expect that documents are sorted by default by date (without clicking on sort by button).

Any ideas ?

Comment: in back office exist sortBy displayDate and modifyDate sort for webcontents and createDate modifyDate for documents.

Comment: yes. i forgot to say that i expect a default sorting.
When the user goes to the documents and media, i expect that documents are sorted by default by date (without clicking on sort by button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook this jsp for the web contents

```
/html/portlet/journal/view-entries.jsp
```

modifing this code

```
if (Validator.isNull(orderByCol)) {
    orderByCol = portalPreferences.getValue(PortletKeys.JOURNAL, "order-by-col", "modified-date");
    orderByType = portalPreferences.getValue(PortletKeys.JOURNAL, "order-by-type", "asc");
}

orderByComparator = JournalUtil.getArticleOrderByComparator(orderByCol, orderByType);
```

For the documents if you see the code of the jsp

```
/html/portlet/document_library/view-entries.jsp
```

modifing this code

```
if (Validator.isNull(orderByCol)) {
    orderByCol = portalPreferences.getValue(PortletKeys.DOCUMENT_LIBRARY, "order-by-col", StringPool.BLANK);
    orderByType = portalPreferences.getValue(PortletKeys.DOCUMENT_LIBRARY, "order-by-type", "asc");
}
```

in the both jsp just change the default value to your desired

Comment: it's nearly good. One folowing question : 
Why this line "orderByType = portalPreferences.getValue(PortletKeys.JOURNAL, "order-by-type", "desc");" make orderByType = "asc"

Comment: because il try to get it from preferences if there is a value use the value otherwise the default "desc". i thing that in this case the preferences is asc

Comment: ok. Can i just set, by default when clicking on web content in the menu, this values ?
It means that when the user opens the web content manager the sort is "created-date" and 'desc'. After he could change this sorting if he wants.

Comment: yes and if the user change it the order with keep that preferences for the future

Comment: yes ok. but when the user returns to the web content manager , i want to use the default settings. Even if he changed the sorting during his last trip in the manager.

Comment: then put saveOrderBy to false before if so it will not save in preferences the order